# SlideIndex Delayed

Tags: jquery, jssor

I am working on a website that has multiple nested sliders (autoplay disabled) and an '.info' div on top. I've got a button that toggles the visibility of that specific div. If you decide to disable the info, thats fine.

But I want it to be displayed again after you reached the end of the slideshow. I've already tried to use the 'slideIndex' option, that works fine if you move through the slideshow very slowly.

The Problem: the slideIndex only gets updated after a couple of milliseconds. If you browse to quickly, it wont update fast enough to  recognize that you already reached the end of the slideshow. And fails to trigger the function.

Is there any other way to make this work?

```
    function SlideshowEndEventHandler(slideIndex, progressBegin, slideshowBegin, slideshowEnd, progressEnd){
        if (slideIndex == 0) {
            $('.info').show();
        }
    };

    jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_SLIDESHOW_END, SlideshowEndEventHandler);
```

Comment: When a slideshow begin to run, the `slideIndex` has already changed. I think you can use `$EVT_PARK` instead of `$EVT_SLIDESHOW_END`.

Comment: @jssor I tried using $EVT_PARK, same result. 

My guess is, that the slideIndex updates as the animation stops. I tried monitoring the slideIndex like this: `$('#next').click(function() {jssor_slider1.$Next();console.log(jssor_slider1.$CurrentIndex());});`

Comment: Lets say I press the `$('#next')` button four times in a row before an animation is completed, the `CurrentIndex` returns a `0` four times and will be updated after the animation is completed.

Comment: The $EVT_POSITION_CHANGE `function(position, fromPosition)` fires more frequently. But the `position` value is not an integer. You can use `Math.floor(position)` to convert it to index of slide.

Comment: It is indeed better, but still not working perfectly. From Slide `1` to `0` it updates instantly, but not from last slide to slide `0`. `Math.floor(position)` wont work as `position` returns numbers from `4.01` to `4.99`, `Math.floor(position)` will then always return the largest integer `4` until  `0 ` is reached and then update to `0`. I guess I'll just have to use the value that `position` returns and update my if statement accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your time and fast response. Much Love.